# Merge/Collapsing identical consecutive elements in a vector

Tags: r

I am trying to merge identical consecutive observations into a collapsed string. A simple example looks as follows:

```
a <- c("H", "H", "H", "N", "T", "N", "T", "H", "N", "T", "T")
[1] "H" "H" "H" "N" "T" "N" "T" "H" "N" "T" "T"

b <- c("HHH", "N", "T", "N", "T", "H", "N", "TT")
[1] "HHH" "N"   "T"   "N"   "T"   "H"   "N"   "TT"

c <- c("HHH", "HHH", "N", "T", "N", "T", "H", "N", "TT", "TT")
[1] "HHH" "HHH" "N"   "T"   "N"   "T"   "H"   "N"   "TT"  "TT"
```

Here, I want to create a function which would take the vector `a` and turn it into either vector `b` or `c`. For example, since the first three observations are all `H`'s, they, together, would become `HHH`. Same with the two `T`'s turning into `TT`. Note that I want to preserve the overall order, and the number of times a given element appears in a consecutive manner is not limited to three times. Thus, for instance, there might be, say, ten `A`'s in a row, which should be transformed into a single `AAAAAAAAAA`.

I have tried to build up step by step from starting with a `for` loop, but could not get much further due to the issue of the non-limited number of repeats in the consecutive occurrence. I have also experimented with using the base `rle` function. But

```
rle(a)
```

gives something like

```
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:8] 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
  values : chr [1:8] "H" "N" "T" "N" "T" "H" "N" "T"
```

where the ten elements became 8, and the positions of the consecutive appearance are not recorded.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gregexpr` with `regmatches`:

```
a <- c("H", "H", "H", "N", "T", "N", "T", "H", "N", "T", "T")

# collapse string
b <- paste(a, collapse = "")

# extract instances of repeated characters
regmatches(b, gregexpr("(.)\\1*", b))[[1]]
# [1] "HHH" "N"   "T"   "N"   "T"   "H"   "N"   "TT"
```

The `stringi` equivalent might be:

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(b, "(.)\\1*")[[1]]
# [1] "HHH" "N"   "T"   "N"   "T"   "H"   "N"   "TT"
```

And the `ore` package for good measure:

```
library(ore)
matches(ore.search("(.)\\1*", b, all = TRUE))
#[1] "HHH" "N"   "T"   "N"   "T"   "H"   "N"   "TT"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with(rle(a), sapply(1:length(values), function(i)
    paste(rep(values[i], lengths[i]), collapse = "")))
#[1] "HHH" "N"   "T"   "N"   "T"   "H"   "N"   "TT"
```

OR

```
sapply(split(a, cumsum(c(TRUE, a[-1] != head(a, -1)))), paste, collapse = "")
#    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8 
#"HHH"   "N"   "T"   "N"   "T"   "H"   "N"  "TT"
```

Comment: Wow - that was fast! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unname(tapply(a, rleid(a), FUN = paste, collapse=""))
#[1] "HHH" "N"   "T"   "N"   "T"   "H"   "N"   "TT"
```

Or with `base R` with `rle` and `tapply`

```
with(rle(a), unname(tapply(a, rep(seq_along(values), lengths), FUN = paste, collapse="")))
#[1] "HHH" "N"   "T"   "N"   "T"   "H"   "N"   "TT"
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be to `paste` together the string and split between repeat characters using regex lookarounds

```
strsplit(paste(a, collapse=""), "(?<=(.))(?!\\1)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "HHH" "N"   "T"   "N"   "T"   "H"   "N"   "TT"
```

Answer (score -1):

Besides the already given solutions, I was interested in a general algorithm that didn't rely on any language specificity.

You said you tried it, but I don't see the non-limited number of repetitions as a real issue. What I've wrote was, basically, iterate over the original array and clone it. If a value of the original array is the same as the last one, instead of adding it as a new item to the new array, concatenate it in the last value of the "clone" array.

Algorithm:

```
Create empty array(w)
Iterate by index(i) of the original vector(v)
   If this is the first entry
      w[1] = v[1]
   Else
      If v[i] is the same as v[i-1]
         Last entry in w is concatenated with v[i]
      Else
         Add v[i] to the end of w
```

In Python:

```python
def collapseVector(v):
    w = [];
    for i in range(len(v)):
        if i == 0:
            w.append(v[i]);
        else:
            if v[i] == v[i-1]:
                w[len(w)-1] = w[len(w)-1] + v[i];
            else:
                w.append(v[i]);
    return w
```